# How to remove unwanted section in profile page for only users?

Tags: profiles

I am using wordpress latest version in a multi-user blog.Interface of the user profile looks like of the sceernshot.

[image: Profile page of the user]

I saw some related posts but can't solve.I want to remove some personal and contact section for users (not site-admin).Please help me to remove sections ! I want to do it without plugin .

Comment: It seems you are either using a plugin or a theme that comes with extended functionality that adds the `Fancier Author [...]` section. Please contact support of that plugin / theme since that section is not the default in WordPress.

Comment: I want to remove personal section (include proofreading section) only.

Comment: You should update your question with specific details. You can hide fields through CSS (they are hardcoded), simply inspect the HTML, collect the CSS classes / IDs that you need and write the corresponding CSS rules. You can then inject your CSS at the `admin_footer` hook for example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the plugin fancier author or fanciest author.
Either modify the setting in there or disable the plugin. 
Hope that solves your problem